# Outlook: Automatically set from address when replying

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have a dozen forwarders sending into a gmail account, I have outlook setup using imap but when I reply I don't want it sending from the Gmail address, instead I want it to come from one of the addresses it was forwarded to.

I know I can set the from address manually by accessing the email's options when writing a new email, but this is going to be forgotten by the users and they are bound to mess it up, I need a way that I can send as some of the forwarded addresses automatically, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the from addresses in Outlook.  I can't recall if Outlook has an "Alias" feature or not, but if it does, that would be the place to look.  Otherwise, you need a slew of accounts with the correct From addresses in them.  Then when you hit Reply, it will reply from the address at which the mail was received.