# Automatic selection of from address when replying to a domain alias email from outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-client

We have 2 domains. Say domain.com and domainalias.com. Mail server is configured in domain.com and domain alias will work as alias in every email account in domain.com.

Example: sales@domain.com will have corresponding alias as sales@domainalias.com

But we wanted to show our customers both domains are separate entities. So I have configured my outlook as described [here](https://axicoms.zendesk.com/entries/63490-How-to-send-from-an-email-alias-in-Outlook-2007).

So, i was able to receive emails from both domain.com and domainalias.com without any duplication of emails.

Sending a reply to an email from sales@domain.com is working without any issue. Proper "from" email account is selected in outlook as "sales@domain.com" when you hit reply button.

But issue comes when replying for alias. For alias, we need to manually select "from" account every time when we hit reply for an email received via sales@domainalias.com. By default, outlook sets default email account for "From". But this can be forgotten/overlooked by operations team members easily.

Is there any way we can tell/configure outlook to pick corresponding "from" account for domainalias.com every-time when reply button is hit for an email sent to domainalias.com?

I did stumble upon following questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/92444/outlook-reply-as-email-address-the-message-was-sent-to) , [here](https://superuser.com/questions/143100/outlook-automatically-set-from-address-when-replying) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/558889/sending-email-as-an-alias-in-outlook). but those haven't provided proper solution for my case.

Outlook Version we are using is 2007. Mail server is MailEnable Standard Edition. Mail server is configured on a Windows 2012 VPS together with our web store.

I did check the email headers of an actual email and an alias email. Both headers are much same except some encrypted signature and message ids. So how did outlook finds out the different and set actual account for domain.com and default account for domainalias.com

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming that your mail server is Exchange? If it is Exchange, you cannot automatically detect the address the email was sent to. When you open and reply to an email, it recognise you based on your Exchange (Active Directory) user rather than on either of the email address. It therefore cannot distinguish which email address the message was sent to. (As you mentioned, the headers don't differ and that's why there is no way to do this.)

A work around would be to create two separate mailboxes (one for each email account) and then delegate access so that the user can see both accounts in Outlook. The mail would be kept seperate and the replies would come from the correct email address. But this may not be the way you wish to work and may create another set of problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. my mail server is MailEnable Standard Edition.

Comment: If you are in a position to consider upgrading to Outlook 2010 or later, there is a new capability whereby you can add a registry setting and Outlook will be forced to prompt you for the sender account:
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\<version>\outlook\options
Value name: forceaccountselection
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1